# Detect if Android is in a car

Tags: android, accelerometer, detection

I am trying to write an application on Android which requires to detect whether the android is currently in a car or not, using *only* accelerometers. Basically the app is suppose to detect if the person holding it is walking or in a car. For walking I just detected spikes in the accelerometer readings but I am not able to find any characteristic of the car. How exactly should I approach this problem?

Comment: A moving car?  What about other vehicles?  What would be an acceptable rate of false positives?

Comment: How would you differentiate between someone in a stopped car and someone driving in a car with perfect suspension on a very good road? I suppose you could detect the acceleration/decelleration from starting/stopping at lights. But would the herky-jerky pattern of someone who's just learning a stick shift look any different from someone who's walking?

Comment: @Michael: The app should detect whether the person is in any motorized vehicle, not a car alone.

Comment: If you're in a car the whole device is stationary relative to the motion of the car, the accelerometer ideally wouldn't show any change in readings at all.

Comment: @Marc: I was thinking something on the lines of the value of acceleration. Assuming an ideal user, the acceleration in a car would be much more than that while walking. However the problem is when does the person stop using the car, I mean even if the car is currently accelerating slowly, it shouldn't be detected as walking...

Comment: Depending on what pocket you keep your phone in, the acceleration pattern of walking should be pretty distinct, especially in a pants pocket. It may be that you'll have luck detecting the difference between walking and non-walking non-zero accelerations, and just assume that if the phone is accelerating in a non-walking pattern for a long enough period of time, you're probably in a vehicle.

Comment: @copperhead did you find any solution? I have same problem statement. I need to identify that use is in moving vehicle. Please guide

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the problem as posed is unsolvable - a phone sitting perfectly still in a parked car (or, for that matter, one running at constant velocity) is completely indistinguishable from one sitting on a desk if you restrict yourself to acceleremoter readings.

For heuristics, I'd just go and record samples, then hone detection algorithms on them. I assume characteristics for (city) traffic would be bouts of near-constant acceleration over a few seconds totalling up to around 10-20 m/s and somehwat more abrupt decelerations of about the same total velocity. I don't think you'd be able to integrate accelerometer readings well enough to accurately track something like a car smoothly accelerating to cruise speed, staying there for an hour and then rolling to a standstill over a long stretch, though.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Its not required for the application to be very accurate. It should roughly detect if the phone is in a *moving* vehicle.

Answer (score 1):

Well obviously, the typical largest differences are acceleration and speed (and perhaps sustained speed). My suggestion, build a profiling application and go have some fun on various types of transportation.